# Duplicate key 'ctrl-e' when editing keymap.cson on atom

Tags: coffeescript, atom-editor

So I'm just trying to override the emmet core short cut but when I edit the `keymap.cson` I'm ending up with this error :

> Failed to load /Users/Me/.atom/keymap.cson
>   Duplicate key 'ctrl-e'

However I'm unsetting it and remaping it so why do I have this error ? This is y conf file :

```
# Your keymap
#
#workaround for emmet mapping of expand-abbreviation

'.editor':
  'ctrl-e': 'unset!'                           # remove all bindings
  'ctrl-e': 'editor:move-to-end-of-line'       # remap core binding
  'alt-cmd-e' : 'emmet:expand-abbreviation'    # alternate binding for emmet

'atom-text-editor':
  'alt-backspace': 'editor:delete-to-previous-word-boundary'
  'alt-delete': 'editor:delete-to-next-word-boundary'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See ["unset! is only useful when you want to disable a key completely. When you want a key to be bound to a different command than the default, it is unnecessary to use unset!"](https://github.com/atom/atom-keymap/issues/110)

I guess they stealth updated it or something, because I had the same problem crop up out of nowhere recently, and commenting out the "unset!" line seems to have remedied it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

So basically you just have to remove `'ctrl-e': 'unset!'`